# Ansible callback plugin: getting timezone of a TaskResult

Tags: ansible

The TaskResult._result dictionary has the "start" and "end" items that contain the start and end times of the task however the times are local times on the remote host where the task was executed.

Is there any attribute I can retrieve that could help me identify the timezone of that remote host/task?

I don't want to use ansible facts as fact gathering is disabled and I don't intend enabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`start` and `end` are populated by `command` module with value of `str(datetime.datetime.now())`. And as far as I know there are not properties that can suggest remote host timezone.

So you should use gathered facts or fetch timezone by other means (for example with `date +%z` command task).